# how to add WHERE clause on SUM? (SELECT JOIN SUM ORDER BY GROUP BY WHERE)

Tags: sql, sqlite

```sql
SELECT player.name,player.handicap, 
SUM(tournament_player.points) as total_points, 
COUNT(tournament_player.player_id) as attendances
FROM player
INNER JOIN tournament_player ON player.id=tournament_player.player_id
GROUP BY player.id
ORDER BY SUM(tournament_player.points) DESC
```

The above works perfectly, but it also selects players with no points at all. i.e where their total of points is equal to 0

How to add a WHERE clause like that

```
WHERE SUM(tournament_player.points) > 0
```

Regardless where I put the clause it always gives me an error near by the WHERE clause :(

```sql
SELECT player.name,player.handicap, 
SUM(tournament_player.points) as total_points, 
COUNT(tournament_player.player_id) as attendances
FROM player
INNER JOIN tournament_player ON player.id=tournament_player.player_id
GROUP BY player.id
WHERE  SUM(tournament_player.points) > 0
ORDER BY SUM(tournament_player.points) DESC
```

**-- UPDATE --**

Thank you both! Wasn't aware of HAVING clause. Working statement:

```sql
SELECT player.name,player.handicap, 
SUM(tournament_player.points) as total_points, 
COUNT(tournament_player.player_id) as attendances
FROM player
INNER JOIN tournament_player ON player.id=tournament_player.player_id
GROUP BY player.id
HAVING  SUM(tournament_player.points) > 0
ORDER BY SUM(tournament_player.points) DESC
```

Comment: Use `HAVING` for aggregation columns. `HAVING SUM(tournament_player.points) > 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `HAVING` when working with Aggregated columns.

```
SELECT player.name,player.handicap, 
SUM(tournament_player.points) as total_points, 
COUNT(tournament_player.player_id) as attendances
FROM player
INNER JOIN tournament_player ON player.id=tournament_player.player_id
GROUP BY player.id
HAVING SUM(tournament_player.points) > 0
ORDER BY SUM(tournament_player.points) DESC
```

Comment: near GROUP: syntax error :/  Never mind, got it to work with the above in my edited post. Thank you!

Comment: You can edit the post with the fix you did to have a working solution so that someone who looks at this question will have an answer that works.